# jQuery.animate(...) is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I would like to create a simple page with snap (to element) scrolling page belows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css">
      .indexPnl{ margin-top:200px; max-height:500px; overflow-y:auto; scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; position:absolute;}
      .indexPnl, .indexPnl li{ list-style: none; }
      .indexPnl img{ width:100px; scroll-snap-align:start;}
      .body{ padding: 200px; }
      .body img{ width: 500px; }
      .page{ width:100%; height:100%; scroll-snap-align:start;}
      .bodyPnl { overflow-y: auto; position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; height:100%; width:100%; scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; }
   </style>

   <script type="text/javascript"><!--
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.body').find('img').css('cursor', 'pointer').on('click', function(){
         var selector=$(this).attr('target');
         console.log('Going to page: '+selector);
         $('.bodyPnl').animate({'scrollTop': $(selector).position().top}, 800, function(){ console.log('DONE'); });
      });
   });
   //--></script>

</head>
<body>

   <div class="bodyPnl">
      <div class="page">
         <ul class="indexPnl">
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
         </ul>

         <div class="body">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/255379/pexels-photo-255379.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" target=".page:eq(1)"/>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="page" >
         <ul class="indexPnl">
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
         </ul>

         <div class="body">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQbYQSFdhlvD9_Inot8wimKt2hdMVXe1KLgog&usqp=CAU" target=".page:eq(2)"/>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="page" >
         <ul class="indexPnl">
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190520/original/pngtree-expression-good-polar-bear-illustration-cartoon-polar-bear-png-image_3885385.jpg"/></li>
         </ul>

         <div class="body">
            <img src="https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/55/13/abstract-golden-holiday-background-bokeh-effect-vector-5995513.jpg" target=".page:first"/>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is:

1. The smooth scrolling animation does not work (even though I remove all unnecessary code);
2. The second click cannot scroll into the 3rd page (I tried offset() and position(), both not working properly;

PS: I had tried, jQuery.scrollTo(..), plugins, but the animation still not working propertly.

The below code is working properly, but I can found the difference .....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <style>
      #body{ width:800px; height:800px; overflow-y:auto; }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">

<div class="target" style="width:500px; height:500px; background-color:blue; opacity:1;">&nbsp;</div>
<button type="button" class="btn">Action</button>

<div style="height:1000px;">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="target2" style="width:500px; height:500px; background-color:blue; opacity:1;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btn').on('click', function(){
      console.log('going to hide the target');
      $('#body').animate({'scrollTop': $('.target2').offset().top}, 800);
   });
});
//--></script>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue. The jQuery.animate(...) is changing the scrollTop value correctly, but the "scroll-snap-type" and "scroll-snap-align" is forcing the scrolling snap!!!!!

The solution:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.body')
      .find('img')
      .css('cursor', 'pointer')
      .on('click', function(){
        var selector=$(this).attr('target');
        $('.bodyPnl')
          /********** IMPORTANT **********/
          .css('scroll-snap-type', 'none')
          /********** ********* **********/
          .animate({
            'scrollTop': '+='+$(selector).position().top}, 
            800 /*Duration*/, 
            function(){ 
              /********** IMPORTANT **********/
              $(this).css('scroll-snap-type', 'y mandatory'); 
              /********** ********* **********/
            }
          )
        ;
    });
 });
```